# Populating array from a database C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnnFinalProject"].ToString());
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT c.partID, p.name, p.categoryID, p.price, p.image, p.subCategoryID, 
                                        (CASE WHEN categoryID = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS casesYN,
                                        (CASE WHEN categoryID = 3 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS OSYN,
                                        (CASE WHEN categoryID = 7 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS HDDYN,
                                        (CASE WHEN subCategoryID = 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS powerYN,
                                        (CASE WHEN subCategoryID = 2 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS processorYN,
                                        (CASE WHEN subCategoryID = 3 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS moboYN,
                                        (CASE WHEN subCategoryID = 4 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS memoryYN,
                                        (CASE WHEN subCategoryID = 5 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS graphicsYN,
                                        (CASE WHEN subCategoryID = 6 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS opticalYN,
                                        (CASE WHEN subCategoryID = 7 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS soundYN
                                        FROM configuration c JOIN parts p ON p.partID = c.partID
                                        WHERE c.customID = @ID", conn);
      conn.Open();
      SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
      while (dr.Read())
      {
        string[] cases = { dr["partID"].ToString() }; 
      }
```

How can I insert into the cases array only the 'partID's that have 'casesYN' value set to Y, as it is now it would insert every 'partID' in the sql query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assumed you don't want to change your SQL query.

Use `List<string>` (requires `using System.Collections.Generic`) instead of `string[]` because it will be easier to add new item into it:

```
var cases = new List<string>();
while (dr.Read())
{
    if(dr["casesYN"].ToString() == "Y")
        cases.Add(dr["partID"].ToString()); 
}
```

If you really need an array, you can always call `ToArray()` method after the loop is finished:

```
string[] casesArray = cases.ToArray();
```

But it will require `using System.Linq` at the top of your file.